# Python: create variables using loop

Tags: bash, scripts, python, dictionary

how can I create a dictionary variables and every variable has an identical number using a loop in python if it is possible?
 for example:

```
counter=0
for line in {1..5}:
     counter +=1
     line_dict_%counter={}
     line_dict_%counter[a]=1
```

output

```
line_dict_1={'a':'1'}
line_dict_2={'a':'1'}
.1
.
.
```

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here, unless they relate to Ubuntu OS use or administering. General programming questions belong on stackoverflow main site

Comment: Apart from the fact that this (type of) question(s)  is better asked on http://stackoverflow.com/, I really don't understand what you are trying to do, nor why? I don't think the question will be understood at SO either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can use the `exec()` function:

```py
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...     exec("line_dict_%s = { 'a': 1 }" % i)
... 
>>> line_dict_1
{'a': 1}
>>> line_dict_2
{'a': 1}
>>> line_dict_3
{'a': 1}
>>> line_dict_4
{'a': 1}
>>> line_dict_5
{'a': 1}
```

Using `exec()` is not a good idea most of the times, i would rather prefer a dictionary to keep the mappings:

```
>>> kv = {}
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...     kv['line_dict_{}'.format(i)] = { 'a': 1 }
... 
>>> kv
{'line_dict_4': {'a': 1}, 'line_dict_5': {'a': 1}, 'line_dict_1': {'a': 1}, 'line_dict_3': {'a': 1}, 'line_dict_2': {'a': 1}}

>>> kv['line_dict_1']
{'a': 1}
>>> kv['line_dict_2']
{'a': 1}
>>> kv['line_dict_3']
{'a': 1}
>>> kv['line_dict_4']
{'a': 1}
>>> kv['line_dict_5']
{'a': 1}
```